# Can I extend Go To Definition to go to the ruby web API or code definition?

Tags: ruby, rake, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am running into problems where I cannot tell if the code I'm reading is standard ruby, some gem or in house code.  To resolve this I would like to extend the capabilities of Go To Definition.  Can I configure or add an extension to sublime that will allow Go To Definition to be more intelligent for ruby?

I added Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User:

`"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~"`

Then I tried to go to definition on this line in my *.rb file:

`@project = ENV['project']`

Go to definition did nothing for both variables. In visual studio, programming.NET, I can hit F1 and go to MSDN.  Or, go to definition and it pulls up the code file or metadata.

I am willing to try tools other than Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubymine is the best tool I've tried:  https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/  ...Unless you are a student or a successful open source developer, the product is not free.

I tried [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel), but it was not powerful enough for my needs.